# emacs inferior lisp scroll

Tags: emacs, scroll, position, lisp

When running Gnu Common Lisp in inferior-lisp mode, each time an expression is typed in to Lisp eval, the window is automatically re-positioned so that the input cursor is at the bottom of the window.  Years ago, it did not do this.  I would like the old behavior, where the text in the window stays in the same place until the printout goes beyond the bottom of the window, and then it puts the input cursor in the center of the window.

I have played with the scroll variables, without effect.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to play with `comint-scroll-show-maximum-output`.